# why does $\left(x+1\right)^{\frac 1x} =e$ when $x=0$

Tags: calculus

Because its really confusing to think that $1^\infty=e$ and that can't be right because wouldn't that mean $1=e$ which would break maths.I'm asking can you explain to me why $\left(x+1\right)^{\frac 1x} =e$ when $x=0$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't. The expression $(x+1)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ isn't defined for $x=0$. What you mean is that $(x+1)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ *converges* to $e$ as $x\to{}0$, Which is a conclusion of the definition of $e$.

Answer (score 1):

In general $1^{\infty}$ is an *indeterminate* form, from which we can not conclude anything. However by rewriting, we can recognise the standard limit which evaluates to $e$.

Setting $t=\frac{1}{x}$ we get

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\,(x+1)^{1/x}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)^t=\color{red}e$$

Comment: so how come when you rewrite it you get a different answer or was this the original answer to begin with

Comment: $1^\infty=1$, $\lim_{a\to1}a^\infty$ is an indeterminate form

Comment: ok that makes sence